# WM_DPICHANGED suggested size is not scaled

Tags: windows

The RECT I get from WM_DPICHANGED is not scaled when I move a window between two monitors with different scaling, I get the same dimensions in pixels whichever monitor I move it to (which results in the window being too large for the monitor or too small for its contents). From using Spy++ it looks like this is the case for other applications too. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hidpi/wm-dpichanged)
 suggests that it should be scaled linearly with DPI by default.

My application is using Qt Quick, which sets `PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE` by default. I've also tried `SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE)` in my own code, which works as I want in terms of window sizing, but the contents are blurry on the secondary monitor (as you'd expect), and `SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2)` which works like the Qt default but scales the window decorations correctly too. In all 3 cases the window contents are scaled correctly.

I'm wondering if there is an issue with Windows itself, or if an update has changed this behaviour, as no application currently resizes correctly for me, and I'm pretty sure some applications, e.g. Explorer and Edge used to at least. I'm currently using Windows 10 17134.

Comment: Turns out it's fixed by manually doing the 1809 Windows 10 update.